# How old would seashells be if I found them 9 ft deep 30 miles from the ocean while digging a pond in North Carolina

Tags: marine-biology, palaeontology

[image] This is a picture of some specimens that I found while digging a pond. I'm 30 miles from the coast in Wilmington, North Carolina and dug down about nine feet past the blue clay and hit a layer of seashells.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleontology_in_North_Carolina) might interest you.